Any way to have colormap on 3D area plots?
I'm trying to plot a waterfall plot of a spectrogram with pgfplots and it sorta works, but there are two main issues

I want the plots to be area plots, meaning the area below each curve is filled white. I am unable to do this without sacrificing the colormap of the curves

There is a white line connecting each of the last data point to the next, but it´s hard to see.


The code I'm using:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view={15}{40},
        xlabel={Frequency (Hz)},
        ylabel={Time (s)},
        zlabel={PSD (W/Hz)},
        x dir=reverse,
        xmin=0, xmax=60,
        colormap/cool,
        shader=flat, % Ensures flat shading
        fill opacity=0.6 % Adjust the fill opacity as needed
    ]
    \addplot3[surf, mesh/ordering=y varies] 
    table[col sep=comma] {spectrogram_data2.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

spectrogram_data2.csv
With the output:

Any way to fix this?
Thanks,
Atli
PS. if the .csv file is missing, just copy this minimal example instead:
0,1,15 
20,1,80 
40,1,40 
60,1,30 
0,2,80 
20,2,20 
40,2,40 
60,2,60 
0,3,90 
20,3,20 
40,3,16 
60,3,80 
0,4,40 
20,4,60 
40,4,30 
60,4,10


Please do not link to external files(can and will break in the future). You can insert the data(preferable a suitable subset) directly in the question or even directly in your code with begin{filecontent*} ...

Really? almost 1000 lines of tabular data?

No. You could show your spectra, but your question would not change if you selected e.g. five point per spectrum.

Please also have a look here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
view={15}{40},
x dir=reverse,
mesh/cols=1,
]
\addplot3[fill=pink, y filter/.expression={y>0.9&&y<1.1?y:nan}] 
table[col sep=comma] {spectrogram_data2.csv} \closedcycle;
\addplot3[surf, y filter/.expression={y>0.9&&y<1.1?y:nan}] 
table[col sep=comma] {spectrogram_data2.csv};

\addplot3[fill=pink, y filter/.expression={y>1.9&&y<2.1?y:nan}] 
table[col sep=comma] {spectrogram_data2.csv} \closedcycle;
\addplot3[surf, y filter/.expression={y>1.9&&y<2.1?y:nan}] 
table[col sep=comma] {spectrogram_data2.csv};

\addplot3[fill=pink, y filter/.expression={y>2.9&&y<3.1?y:nan}] 
table[col sep=comma] {spectrogram_data2.csv} \closedcycle;
\addplot3[surf, y filter/.expression={y>2.9&&y<3.1?y:nan}] 
table[col sep=comma] {spectrogram_data2.csv};

\addplot3[fill=pink, y filter/.expression={y>3.9&&y<4.1?y:nan}] 
table[col sep=comma] {spectrogram_data2.csv} \closedcycle;
\addplot3[surf, y filter/.expression={y>3.9&&y<4.1?y:nan}] 
table[col sep=comma] {spectrogram_data2.csv};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


The same plot where /addplot s are in reverse order:


I thought the OP wanted white filling and then the curves become indistinct?

@cfr: I do not understand the thing about curves becoming indistinct!? I chose pink, as white can not be seen on the white background. There must be something I have completely misunderstood.

That's one step closer! But the areas still look transparent :/

The areas are not transparent. You might want to plot them in reverse order. I am away from a computer right now.

The opacity setting didn’t affect the transparency in the original code. The areas that you set as pink were supposed to be white. Otherwise, this solves the question.
